# Strange and out of place

Tags: bash, powershell, zsh

I try my best to keep the drives on my PC organized, but the other day I came across a file I had never seen before. First I ran it through my Antivirus and it came out clean, but I am still troubled by it. I have had some classes in Html programming and have used a little JavaScript to do some very basic web pages for class, but I have never seen the likes of this, (Sample:  `WT   [:? fJ/ |  v?_ k  ?  ??E L? N? ޠZ և A ? $ ?  Z? p     ? ?  A\`). If the file had not been out of place on my drive I would not have been the wiser. I would just like to identify the language and know if there may be cause for concern.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: Is this the file name or the content?

Comment: that looks like the CONTENT of the file ... and it seems likely to be in one of the multi-byte character sets. /////  so ... [1] what is the file name? ///// [2] if you view the file content with something like notepad++, does it show different characters where those `?` chars are.

Comment: if `find` and/or `stat` are installed in your `bash/zsh` env you might get something useful from `type filename` and/or `stat filename`; also of interest would be the datetime stamp of the last time the file was modified (see output from `stat filename` or `ls -l filename`) and if 'recent' then the datetime may jog your memory of what you were doing at the time (eg, `Hmmmm, this past Sat afternoon ~4:15 pm? Oh, yeah, I was installing XYZ game ...`) that may shine a light on the source

Comment: This site is primarily for programming questions - you might get a better response if you move your question to https://superuser.com/ which is more for systems administration…